# binary literal type conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

I wrote the following code:

```
g++ -x c++ - -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wconversion <<__EOF && ./a && echo -e "\e[1;31mOK\e[0m" || echo -e "\e[1;31mfailed!\e[0m"
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
template< typename T >
struct traits_type
{
    typedef std::uint8_t op_type;
    // ... typedefs
};
template< typename T, typename traits = traits_type< T > >
struct generator
{
    typedef typename traits::op_type op_type;
    // typedefs...
    void operator () () const { return; }
    template< typename ...OPS >
    void operator () (op_type const op, OPS && ...ops)
    {
        sequence.push_back(op);
        return operator () (std::forward< OPS >(ops)...);
    }
    // member functions etc...
    std::vector< op_type > sequence;
};
int main()
{
    struct T { }; // Some type, which does not concern us in this context.
    generator< T > g;
    g(0b00000000, 0b10101010);
    g(0b01010101);
    // ... using of g.sequence, say, in state machine
    return 0;
}
__EOF
```

As I intended, this code will allow me to create a sequence of some (so-called) "opcodes". But numeric literals as `0b00000000` are treated as int. This leads to the fact, that there is the conversion of a larger signed integer type to an smaller unsigned integer type in the end. It may have an undesirable side effects. There is no suffix to denote an unsigned integer type with size of one byte in **C++**.
How can I avoid this using a pure **C++11**?
I don't want to use `static_cast` and the others, because this leads to code bloating (multiple parentheses and at least one symbol to name the `static_cast`-wrapper function).
The solution could be to use a user-defined literal, say `0b00000000_op`, that looks better than `o(0b00000000)`. But operator must be a function template like a:

```
template< template T, typename traits = type_traits< T > >
constexpr
typename traits::op_type
operator "" _op (typename traits::op_type && op)
{
    return std::move(op);
}
```

but in **C++11** there is no such syntax... and what to do with `T` template parameter if any?

Comment: Why not just `unsigned char operator "" _uc`? What's with the template stuff?

Comment: Because `op_type` may have a different value in the future.

Comment: And can depends on value of `T`.